# Different Hive location for different commands

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, hadoop2

I have a hive external table in my production (let's say table1). When I do `desc formatted table1` I can see some location. When I do `desc formatted table1 partition(date = 22042019)` instead, it's getting different hdfs location.

E.g:

```
desc formatted table1

Location: user/hive/warehouse/db.db/loc1

Desc formatted table1 partition (date = 22042019")

Location: x/y/loc/date=22042019
```

Answer (score 1):

Table and partition locations can be different. When you are adding partition without specifying location or dynamically creating partitions during insert, partition folders normally created inside table location. But you can use `alter table add partition ...location` ... or `[alter table partition set location][1]`  In this case you can create partitions outside table location. Also you can `alter table set location` and set different location. All existing partitions and their locations in this case will remain as is and be accessible, though their base location and table location are different.

Comment: What happens when I query table. Does it fetch data from table or partition location.

Comment: @user11673791 If table is partitioned each partition metadata is checked separately of course. Data is fetched from each partition location. They all can have different locations

Comment: @user11673791 Only this: DESCRIBE FORMATTED table_name PARTITION(key='value'); You can write a program in the shell use show partitions table_name and loop and call describe formatted for each partition or use direct access to the metastore if applicable